# How to write a batch file to rename files in numerically order within a particular folder?

Tags: batch-file

I have a file contain three  pictures, they named ape.jpg, 123.jpg, zoo.jpg
I want to write a batch file, it can rename all three pictures into a numerical order.

```
ape.jpg -> (1).jpg
123.jpg -> (2).jpg
zoo.jpg -> (3).jpg
```

I don't really care about the original names and orders of those pictures, I know this can be done in any version of windows by manually go into that folder and select them all, rename one of them to (1), and rest of pictures will order themself numerically. but I want to do this with batch file.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with a FOR loop and a counter variable.  The `for` will loop over the output of `dir` to get a full list of files, and then rename them sequentially.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=1
for /F %%a in ('dir /B *.jpg') do (
  echo ren "%%a" "(!i!).jpg"
  set /a i+=1
)
endlocal
```

This makes no guarantee about what order they appear in, but it should operate on all *.jpg files in the current directory.  Run this and it will show you the rename commands that it would use.  To make it actually rename the files, remove the `echo` before the line with `ren`.

Comment: This method (plain `for` command) may cause that some files be processed (renamed) more than one time, depending on the place where the renamed files are inserted in the `*.jpg` wild card. You should use `for /F %%a in ('dir /B *.jpg') ...` instead in order to avoid this problem.

Comment: And If want to keep the file name a.txt -> 001 a.txt. What should I do then?