# Retain original order when renaming files to number sequence?

Tags: bash, batch-file, rename, batch-rename

Here's an example script with enabledelayedexpansion for renaming files:
[How to write a batch file to rename files in numerically order within a particular folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551660/how-to-write-a-batch-file-to-rename-files-in-numerically-order-within-a-particul)

How to retain the original file order though?
I need a possible solution for Bash and for Batch (DOS/Windows).

---

Edit: OK - I think a specific example of my situation for batch is necessary to understand the sorting issue.
What I have are .cab files in a folder, like this:
"1_1.cab" - "1_120.cab"
I try to understand how to rename the files for the result:
"1.cab" - "120.cab"
In theory there must be a way to take care about all "1_" while renaming to achieve the original order.

---

possible solution for batch in this specific case:
`for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%G in ('dir /b /A:-D *.cab') do rename %%G_%%H %%H`

Comment: The question you are referring to is about DOS batch files. Here you ask about bash. So the relationship between these two questions is rather vague and the solutions will be very different.

Comment: I want to know both actually. How could I solve this with a DOS batch file?

Comment: solving that in DOS? Absolutely no idea, sorry. But I think you can run bash scripts in Windows by installing CygWin.

Comment: It depends upon what you consider the original file order to be. Especially as those in the example you linked were not in alphabetical, numercal, or natural order, and there was nothing in that question to show sizes/creation time/last modified/last accessed. It would there help if were to be more specific, on how we're supposed to base our suggestions or answers. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61805522/edit), to make that clarification. Please also note, that the function of this site isn't to write code for people, it is to assist them with their failing code.

Comment: OK. For Batch in my specific situation(see my last edit) an applicable method could be: for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%G in ('dir /b /A:-D *.cab') do rename %%G_%%H %%H

Comment: Well, regardless of your edit, it still is unclear, because your files aren't really in numerical order, because file `1_121.cab` is listed before file `1_3.cab`. Therefore the example you've now posted and the possible solution, have no relationship to the link you've used. Additionally the possible solution you've offered could perhaps be made more robust too: `@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe .:1_0*.cab .:1_1*.cab .:1_2*.cab .:1_3*.cab .:1_4*.cab .:1_5*.cab .:1_6*.cab .:1_7*.cab .:1_8*.cab .:1_9*.cab 2^>NUL') Do @Set "_=%%~nxG" & Call Ren "%%G" "%%_:~2%%"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I suggest you to try:

```sh
for file in *; do ((i++)); mv "$file" "$i.${file##*.}"; done
```

This will rename all the not hidden files of the current directory to files having as name a number followed by the same suffixe as the original file. The numbers will respect the existing order of the files.

Also be sure you have no file having a number as basename: you risk to erase it.

If you are not sure of the result, change `mv` into `echo mv` for seing what is going to happen before you actually do it.

Comment: Note that this is missing a substantial amount of quoting needed to work with filenames with spaces, glob characters, etc. `mv "$file" "$i.${file##*.}"` would be safer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: you are absolutely right. I was distracted. I realised it later and came back to my computer to correct it, but found you already commented this.

Answer (score 0):

After the OP edited its question saying he only wants to strip the file names from their prefix `1_`, I suggest a new solution:

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file#1_}"; done
```

If the prefix can be any number followed by an underscore, it is possible to adapt this latter solution.